# Kubernetes List All Containers that are not running

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath, customcolumn

How to list All Containers that are not running using **Kubectl** command.  I want output like

```
CONTAINER_NAME   STATUS        POD_NAME       NAMESPACE <br>
container_1      Running       pod_1          ns1       <br>
container_2      Not Running   pod_2          ns2       <br>
container_3      Running       pod_2          ns2       <br>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Running
```

Above command will above list down all pods, not in Running status for default namespace.

if you want to run a command across all namespaces & list down all PODS

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Running --all-namespaces
```

You can also print custom column as per require if you want to print **Namespace**

```
kubectl get pod --field-selector status.phase!=Running -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NAMEDPACE:.metadata.namespace
```

Final command the way you are looking forward with columns

```
kubectl get pod --field-selector status.phase!=Running -o=custom-columns=POD_NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NAMEDPACE:.metadata.namespace,CONTAINER_NAME:.spec.containers[*].name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already created a command to print pod_name, container name and status.
kubectl get po -A -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"pod: "}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{range .status.containerStatuses[*]}{"\tcontainer_name: "}{.name}{"\n\tcontainer_status: "}{.ready}{"\n"}{end}'
But I want the container without running status.

Comment: i think above command share is printing the container in not running state only maybe.

Comment: This does not seem to list pods that are have a status of CrashLoopBackOff.

Comment: coz for crashingLoopBackOff phase of POD will be Running only as it's Running but crashing so ideally not get listed with above command.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that `.status.phase` **is actually the scheduling state, not the actual state**. It can be in "Running" state and your containers in the pod still in a crashloop. What I do is to check if the latest `containerStatuses` is in a waiting state. If yes, than those will be the stuck containers:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.containerStatuses[-1:].state.waiting)]}{.metadata.name}: {@.status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to above answer, I had a special usecase where I wanted to get all the non-running pods names to remove them.
So I used this to get the names as list

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespace --field-selector status.phase!="Running" -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'
```